# How to export an obj file with mtl file in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, graphics, reverse-engineering

I am a new bee in unity. One day I am looking for some method to reverse Unity application and extract the **obj** model in it. I try to use [UnityStudio](https://github.com/Perfare/AssetStudio) and [AssetsBundleExtractor](https://7daystodie.com/forums/showthread.php?22675-Unity-Assets-Bundle-Extractor), two tools extract **obj** model and texture file successfully.

When I open the **obj** file in VS Code, I found **vt** and **f** attributes but I notice that there is no **mtllib** command to relate texture and **obj** file. And in the same folder of **obj** file, there is no **mtl** file found.

After some searching, seems that unity doesn't need **mtl** file to associate texture with **obj** model.

So I wonder how unity associate **obj** with texture without a **mtl** file?

And if I want to load this model using some C++ library like **assimp** (in OpenGL), how can I do this with out **mtl** file associate texture with **obj** model (I want to load model with a texture cover it)?

If there exist some methods to export **obj** model from unity with **mtl** file associate **obj** with texture?

Waiting for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, you want to reverse engineer an asset file to extract assets, correct? There are a few tools that can help you do this. As for the obj and mtl files. I deal primarily with FBX and MAT and the principles are almost the same, so you could try extracting the raw textures from the asset bundle and then building a new .mtl file for the obj?

I used this the last time I was extracting from asset bundles and it's pretty good.
[Unity Assets Bundle Extractor](https://7daystodie.com/forums/showthread.php?22675-Unity-Assets-Bundle-Extractor)

I did a bit of digging and found this which might point you in the right direction.
[Question about importing .OBJ with .mtl - Unity Forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/question-about-importing-obj-with-mtl.81294/)

Good luck!